# I need to differentiate two touch events. How can I differentiate two events?

Tags: ios, uievent

I'm catching touch events. I need to differentiate two events
1) User touched a screen and then lifted a finger
2) User touched screen and don't lifted a finger 
How can I differentiate two events?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 if (isFirstCase)
 {}
 if (isSecondCase)
 {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute `(NSSet *)touches` contains `UITouch` objects each of them contain several helpful properties:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger tapCount
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval timestamp
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UITouchPhase phase
@property(nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSArray *gestureRecognizers

typedef enum {
    UITouchPhaseBegan,
    UITouchPhaseMoved,
    UITouchPhaseStationary,
    UITouchPhaseEnded,
    UITouchPhaseCancelled,
} UITouchPhase;
```

Phase and tapCount is very usable property to identify the type of touch. 
Check if you can use UIGestureRecognizers. `NSArray *gestureRecognizers` - the array of this objects which related to this particular touch.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use gesture recognizers:

- [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer) for simple taps
- [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) for long taps

First you need to register the gesture recognizers:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self 
                                         action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[myView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Then you have to write the action methods:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // simple tap
}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // long tap
}
```